# SUBST Command is Broken in Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-10

Has anyone had success in getting SUBST to work in Windows 10?

In Windows 7 and prior, I could go into a command prompt (without admin privileges) and enter this command:

```
SUBST R: "C:\BlahBlah\XXX\YYY"
```

and an R: drive would appear in Explorer, mapped to the specified folder. This behavior seems to be broken in Windows 10, even if I run the command prompt with elevated privileges.

Comment: subst works perfectly, like always. Substr is not a dos command

Comment: @Sporri - When you say SUBST works perfectly, do you see your mapped drive letter show up in Explorer? I don't. The drive letter shows up "perfectly" within the command prompt window, but it does not seem to be propagated to the rest of the system.

Comment: Yes, you might need to close all explorer windows and open a new one

Comment: @Sporri - Closing and Reopening Explorer did nothing.

Comment: See my edit below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SUBST run through elevated command/PowerShell prompt only reflects in the elevated prompt and NOT in Windows Explorer (GUI).

Run the command WITHOUT elevation and you should see it in Explorer as a drive.  Don't forget this virtual mapping will be cleared upon reboot, unless you make it permanent through the registry.

---

[SUBST Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Can we get more details on making it permanent using the registry?

Comment: I wanted to know the same thing as @ScottBeeson . Happily answered by someone on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots